# When timing a method (to determine efficency) should user input and output be included in the time?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, benchmarking, timing

If I want to test the speed at which a method returned, should I include its output? For example

```
public static void fizzBuzz2(int n)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(i % 3 == 0  && i % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
            else if(i % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println("Fizz");
            else if(i % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("Buzz");
            else
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

I'm going to modify so that instead of printing to the console it will write to a file. Should the time writing to the file be included in timing? Fortunately the parameter is passed in but in the situations where userinput is taken, how does benchmarking take place?

I was thinking of commenting out the `System.out.println` statements but I'm not sure if the optimizer would then get rid of the entire program :/

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to measure. Micro-benchmarks are extremely complex to do well in Java, due to all the optimizations that may or may not happen at runtime, the GC, etc. If you're serious about benchmarking, look for JMH and Caliper.

Comment: @JBNizet if I have a completely different implementation of FizzBuzz I want to know which is faster. I know FizzBuzz is kind of a silly example, but say you had a program that printed the prime factors from 2 up to n. Would you count the output (or just comment out the output)?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you're trying to measure. If generating the output is what matters, thne you should definitely measure it, because one implemenation might be slower at generating the output than the other. If the efficiency of the algorithm is what you want to measure, then make the algorithm return output rather than writing it, and make sure both implementation use the same way date structures to generate the returned value.

Comment: @JBNizet I was sort of thinking its dependent on the specific system how long output takes, e.g. writing a file to a SSD vs HD. But I guess that's irrelevant when comparing because all output would take the same time on the same system. Also why do you keep saying it depends on what I'm trying to measure? Haven't I made it clear?

Comment: @Celeritas: No, you haven't.  You want to know "which implementation is faster."  It's a question for _you_ to decide whether output time should be included in that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well that's the whole point of the question is should output time be included.

Comment: We're telling you that's a nonsensical question.  Whatever you want to test for speed is what you should measure.  Whatever you dont care about, should not be measured.  There are valid reasons to want to measure the output, and valid reasons not to, and we cannot decide for you.

Answer (score 0):

store the processing time in a variable and *then* save it to a file, then you won't have to worry about any extra time it takes writing it.
 calling on some of the comments here, I'm not sure what level of precision you're looking for, but a simple `long start = System.currentTimeMillis()` before the process starts and subtracting that from a second timestamp at completion will give you a good idea. You can do file saving and output after you capture the end time